# Trying to convert strings into unicode to load UFT-8 XML file

Tags: python, xml, unicode, utf-8

I am building an EPG scraper that creates a UTF-8 encoding XML file. All is well, except I am having trouble encoding all the bits of strings I am stitching together into a unicode string that I can load into my file.

My code is as so:

```
starttime = datetime.strptime(' '.join([str(now.year).encode('UTF-8'), str(e[4].encode('UTF-8')), str(e[0].encode('UTF-8'))]), '%Y %a %d %b %I:%M%p').strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
endtime = datetime.strptime(' '.join([str(now.year).encode('UTF-8'), str(e[4].encode('UTF-8')), str(e[1].encode('UTF-8'))]), '%Y %a %d %b %I:%M%p').strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

global epg_data

clean_channel = str(channel.encode('UTF-8').replace('&', '&amp;').replace("'", "&apos;").replace('"', '&quot;').replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;'))
clean_e2 = str(e[2].encode('UTF-8').replace('&', '&amp;').replace("'", "&apos;").replace('"', '&quot;').replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;'))
clean_e3 = str(e[3].encode('UTF-8').replace('&', '&amp;').replace("'", "&apos;").replace('"', '&quot;').replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;'))
div_list3 = div_list2.encode('UTF-8').replace('&', '&amp;').replace("'", "&apos;").replace('"', '&quot;').replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;')
e5 = str(e[5].encode('UTF-8').replace('&', '&amp;').replace("'", "&apos;").replace('"', '&quot;').replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;'))

epg_data = ''.join([u'<programme start="',starttime,u' +0100" stop="',endtime,u' +0100" channel="',clean_channel,u'">\n', \
u'<title lang="eng">',e5,u'</title>\n<desc lang="eng">',clean_e2,' ',clean_e3,u'</desc>\n<icon src="',div_list3,u'" />\n', \
u'<country>UK</country>\n</programme>'])
```

I am hitting a problem when trying to parse the following (as printed to IDLE):

```
<programme start="20180514180500 +0100" stop="20180514190000 +0100" channel="BBC Entertainment">
<title lang="eng">Hustle</title>
<desc lang="eng">Hustle Tiger Troubles Season 6 Episode 3/6When a notorious hardman demands Â£500,000 from Albert by the end of the week, the team tries to raise the cash by targeting a playboy in possession of a gold tiger worth a vast amount of money. Emma is sent to persuade the owner to lend the item to a major museum, in the hope the gang can steal it, but an impenetrable vault causes complications. Guest starring former Doctor Who star Colin Baker and Lolita Chakrabarti : 8.2</desc>
<icon src="http://my.tvguide.co.uk/channel_logos/60x35/68.png" />
<country>UK</country>
</programme>
```

The generated error is as so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python27\Kodi\Sky TV Guide Scraper.py", line 332, in soup_to_text
    u'<country>UK</country>\n</programme>'])
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 75: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've sort of lost my way a bit with sorting this out, so any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: How do you save the file? How do you parse it later? The parser seems to be attempting ascii. Try adding `"<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“utf-8”?>\n"` to the top of the xml.

Comment: Any reason you are using python 2? Python 3 has been around for nearly a decade and has better unicode support.

Comment: the correct header is added later in the program. the issue is well before then though. the issue is trying to convert ascii strings to unicode as above. any ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: actually, i believe adding this line of code has resolved my issue: 'epg_data2 = unicode(epg_data, 'UTF-8')'

Comment: You aren't converting ascii to unicode, you are converting utf-8 encoded binary to unicode. The reason why your fix works is that it decodes the utf-8 encoded strings. But you shouldn't do all that work. Remove the utf-8 stuff from your original code and work in unicode the whole time.

Comment: `utf-8` encoding inside a `cp1254-2` char(`utf8-euro != cp1254-euro`). your char is `\u20ac35` but your file haven't  valid `utf-8` encoding. Yor default char range is 0-127 but got 0xC2, never use decoding/encoding if you know "what you want !".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode support is rather confusing in python 2. That's in the top 50 reasons to move to python 3. Encoding a `str` or `unicode` to utf-8 returns a `str` object which is indistinguishable from a regular ASCII string. You just have to remember that its encoded. `str(channel.encode('utf-8'))` is a bit redundant (its already a `str` so the `str(..)` part isn't necessary.

When you called `''.join([u'<programme start="', etc...])`, you mixed `unicode` and `str` objects, so python tried to promote everything to `unicode`. You knew that some of those `str` strings were really utf-8 encoded strings, but python didn't know that. Python 3 would know that and would bark loudly.

The general rule for unicode is to do conversions at the edges. Decode when reading stuff in, encode when writing stuff out. If you had skipped the `encode('utf-8')` stuff and just stuck with unicode in the snippet you gave, it would have worked.

Two other things to consider: Python can escape the strings for you. `cgi.escpae` is good for older HTML. `xml.sax.saxutils.escape` is good for XML and XHTML and HTML5. And `str.format` can help make more readable string formatting.

Putting it all together...

```
starttime = datetime.strptime(' '.join([now.year, e[4], e[0], '%Y %a %d %b %I:%M%p').strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
endtime = datetime.strptime(' '.join([now.year, e[4], e[1]]), '%Y %a %d %b %I:%M%p').strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

global epg_data

epg_data = u"""\
<programme start="{starttime} +0100" stop="{endtime} +0100" channel="{channel}">
    <title lang="eng">{e5}</title>
    <desc lang="eng">{e2} {e3}</desc>
    <icon src="{div_list2}" />
    <country>UK</country>
</programme>""".format(channel=escape(channel), starttime=starttime, 
    endtime=endtime,e5=escape(e5), e2=escape(e2), e3=escape(e3), 
    div_list2=escape(div_list2))
```